# What does PHP do when I hit ESC?

Tags: php, background-process

Suppose I have a pretty lengthy PHP script taking exactly 60 seconds.

I connect to mysite.com/thatscript.php, I'm pretty sure I connected, then the script starts running. After 5 seconds I hit escape. Then I hit Ctrl+R, and wait another 5 seconds, then repeat 12 times.

What will happen and why?

/edit: I actually tested and it puts me to wait but I can't distinguish whether Apache keeps me waiting, or another concurrent script, or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what PHP is doing.

Pressing esc will normally stop a browser loading the page.

If you lengthy script is also using a session, then all other request will wait until the previous script finished because of session locking.

Session locking related: [How does session_start lock in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531584/how-does-session-start-lock-in-php)

If you want to control how PHP handles the user stopping the request look at: http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Comment: +1 for connection handling link which will probably address all of OPs questions.

Comment: But this has nothing to do with Apache, does it? If I open 6 requests simultaneously only then will Apache intervene is this correct?

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL Apache is just a layer between the browser and PHP.